# 2010 - Email not sending when custom variable is in to field

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, workflow-variable

In our AD database, the email addresses stored in Sharepoint are often wrong and cause problems for our sites. Unfortunately we don't get much assistance from our AD database administrators, so I need to find a fix around this.

Currently, I am doing the following:

[image: workflow]

If a specific field is empty, it creates a variable with the Login Name from a user picked from a People Picker field called Student. Then another variable is set to combine the first variable and @syr.edu to form the email address. Then it forces the Current Item to update with the variable Email Address. Lastly, it sends an email address with the updated Current Item.

However, this does not seem to work. Previously, I tried to just put the Email Address variable in the to: field and set it to an email address, but it would not send out. Any ideas on what might be missing? Or is there another approach?

Comment: I would start by putting a log entry after each step to show each value. So `Log Current Item:Student`, `Log Variable: User ID`, `Log Variable: Email Address`

Comment: Why do you send to `Current Item:Student` and not to `Current Item:SUID`? Isn't the purpose of SUID field to store the real/up-to-date email address? Also: are you sure variable `User ID`stores what you expect? Did you check if `Current Item:SUID` contains the correct value?

Comment: @Evariste SUID is a separate field from Student. Student is the People Picker field we use to get the Student's Information. SUID is just a text field we manually enter numbers into.

Currently, I have User ID set to get the Login Name from the Current Item in Student.

Comment: @ErinL These are my logs when testing using myself:
Current Item in Student = 830 (I set this field to show the Login Name so I'm not sure why that is appearing)
User ID = AD\nafoster
Email Address = nafoster@syr.edu

Theoretically, if I tell the Current Item in the Student field to update with the Email Address variable, it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure you can update a People field with a string variable containing the email address...

Comment: @Evariste That does seem to be the case. This makes me wonder why just putting in the Email Address variable I created into the to field doesn't work. It seems that others have used it with success before.

Comment: Next, I would try setting `Variable: User ID` = `Current Item:Student` as string. Then in the next line, see if you can set `Variable: User ID` to `Variable: User ID` as Login Name. Then log `Variable: User ID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using your Email address variable in To filed rather than using the student field? Student field will not update if the email address that you are passing into it doesnt match the one in the AD.

Comment: This is something I have tried. I have set the To field as the Email Address variable and set it to output an email address, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Is your Email Address string variable getting set with the email address? is your workflow getting to the email step? or is it failing at the update step? try removing the update step. Check in the ULS logs what is actually happening when your workflow tries to send email

Comment: After looking into the logs after the update item step was removed, the email address generated for the Email Address variable is AD\nafoster@syr.edu which is causing the message not to send.

Is there a way to remove the AD\ and just get the nafoster ?

Comment: There are utility actions for string manipulation in SP designer. So you can extract a substring from the Email Address variable or replace AD\ with blank space...

Comment: `Extract Substring from Index of String` starting at 3 would accomplish what HarryB suggsted.

Comment: Adding the Extract Substring as @HarryB worked. Thank you both for your help.